# How to set an env variable that lasts until the building finishes?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

How to set an env variable using `config.toml` or `Cargo.toml` that lasts for the end of the building time.

Setting it in `config.toml` doesn't help because I want to use some combined values as follows.

```
[env]
VAR="${pwd}/d --g ${pwd}/aaa"
```

Note that I can't use `build.rs` too because I want the env var to be set until the building finishes.

---

I think rust devs shoulld add some more thing like `build.rs` but execut it before building the dependencies.

Comment: You can always run any shell command with variables that last just for the invocation with `var1=val1 var2=val2 command args`, e.g., `VAR="${pwd}..." cargo build`

Comment: @BallpointBen I want to use it in the build script because the example I used is a simplified one.